# PopTo - selectedViewController (Swift)

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have some ViewControllers with one NavigationController (From the first ViewController). In every segue I am using NavController.pushViewController. Finally in my last Controller I want to make a popViewController , but I want to skip two screens (double pop). The reason I want it that way is because I want to keep the stack as it is. First controller is a home "menu" , second "Map" , third "Chapters" , fourth "text" and in the "last" controller after one event I want to go back to "Chapters".
I tried to init() the ChaptersViewController but I am loosing the Navigation stack.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.popToViewController(animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:) which pops view controllers from the stack until `chaptersVC` becomes the top one:

```
let chaptersVC = navigationController.viewControllers[2] // third ViewController in the stack
navigationController.popToViewController(chaptersVC, animated: true)
```